# How to collect a limited data every day using flutter and firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a flutter app which collect only 15 appointments every day and if the appointment number reach 15 the app shows snack bar saying today is full. I have coded the app but it's not working for the next day , it's showing the snack bar saying it's full though I have not entered ant appointments for next day. How do I solve this ? Please help

this is my code

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: Hos(),
  ));
}

class Hos extends StatefulWidget {
  const Hos({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Hos> createState() => _HosState();
}

class _HosState extends State<Hos> {

 DateTime now = DateTime.now();
 DateTime today = DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day);
 TextEditingController name = TextEditingController();
 TextEditingController number= TextEditingController();
final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance; 
final snackBar = const SnackBar(
  content: Text('Reached the limit!'),
);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton( onPressed: () async{
       int total = await Appointment.getCount() + 1;
       if(total < 15 && Appointment.Date == today){
        await Appointment.add(name.text,number.text); name.clear(); number.clear(); 
       }else{
        // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        name.clear(); number.clear();
       }     
        } ,
        
      child: const Icon(Icons.app_registration),),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children:  [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: TextField(
              controller: name,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Name',
                hintText: 'Enter Name',
              ),
            ),
          ),
      Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: TextField(
              controller: number,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly] ,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(   
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Number',
                hintText: 'Enter Number',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Appointment {
  String Name;
  int Number;
static DateTime Date = DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day);
  Appointment({
    required this.Name,
    required this.Number,
   
  });

 Map<String, dynamic> tomap() {
    Map<String,dynamic> request = {"Name": Name, "Number": Number, "Date": Date};
    return request;
  }

 static Future add(name,number)async{
    final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance; 
     var users = db.collection("Appointments");  
     await users.add(Appointment(Name: name, Number: int.parse(number),).tomap());
  }

 static Future<int> getCount() async {
  final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance; 
    int count = await db
        .collection('Appointments')
        .get()
        .then((value) => value.size);
    return count;
  }
  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code, you are getting the whole list of Appointments so the count is still greater than your limit. To achieve this, apply a filter to the getCount() function.

As you are saving dates with every appointment, in getCount, just write this ->

```
int count = await db
    .collection('Appointments').where("Date", isEqualTo:today)
    .get()
    .then((value) => value.size);
```

Comment: Damn it's working thank you so much bro  @Raushan Kumar